# What are the practical implications of changing the rolloff factor of a root-raise cosine filter?

Tags: communication, filter, digital-logic

This is in regards to digital communications. I have a link I've set up using [GNURadio](http://www.gnuradio.org) that's sending BPSK modulated data through water via a LED. I can control the roll-off factor, $\beta$, of the [root-raise cosine filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised-cosine_filter). What are the practical implications of this number? It seems that any value should work fine, since it fulfills the nyquist criteria (adjacent symbols have zero energy at the current symbol's sample point) and the energy/frequency is constrained. Is it mostly just a way to control the affects of jitter vs. slight savings in bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bandwidth-saving measure.  Consider if instead of raised-cosine waveforms you used square waves (the beta = 1 case) - lots more harmonics, more bandwidth required.  The raised-cosine limits the bandwidth at the expense of making the baseband signal more difficult to produce and detect.

Comment: I don't see how using a RRC makes, the "more difficult to produce and detect." It's all the same filter, no matter what the roll-off is. Besides, that still leaves the question of how the roll-off (other than at 1) affects things - e.g. why choose 0.35 instead of 0.55?

Comment: Smoother roll-off gives worse ISI for 2 reasons: (1) No one ever gets the local bit-clock exactly synchronized with the remote bit-clock. For a given error in the local bit-clock, smoother roll-off produces worse ISI. (2) Nice sharp edges between bits make it much easier (for humans looking at an o'scope) to detect where one bit ends and the next bit begins. Smoother transitions generally cause the local bit-clock to have worse synchronization error (than sharper transitions), leading to even worse ISI.

Comment: I"m glad someone can explain it better than I.  I majored in comm theory but havent touched it for years.